# What is the corresponding artifact for Config.groovy of grails 2.x in grails 3.x?

Tags: grails

I want to migrate an application from grails 2.4.4 to grails 3.3.9.
As the structure of the conf directory in grails 2.x is completely different from 3.x, there is no config.groovy in 3.x anymore. In config.groovy of 2.x I used to define lists of constants for my select boxes like:

```
  metals=['au','ag','pl']
```

and I accessed them via

```
static List getMetals() {
    grails.util.Holders.config.metals
}
```

in my groovy code.

What is the corresponding way in 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking out the upgrade guides:

http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.html

http://docs.grails.org/3.2.0/guide/upgrading.html#upgrading2x

config.groovy, by default becomes application.yml, but you can convert that to application.groovy, and there is a script in the external config plugin that will help with that:

http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/external-config

In general it is conserdered back practice to use the holders, it would be better to use either an injected bean/service
GrailsApplication grailsApplication

grailsApplication.config.etc

Or wire in a bean using resources. The only reason to use holders is in another object that is outside of grails, that for some reason, you can't wire up as a bean. In that cases there is now a Holders class, that you can get the config from. Here's some other ways to get at the config from an OCI blog:

http://grailsblog.objectcomputing.com/posts/2016/08/31/retrieving-config-values.html